# What is the difference between name vs singular_name in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

What is the difference between name vs singular_name in Wordpress custom post types? Only name appears to have affect inside CMS.

Answer (score 2):

The `singular_name` is used for the language in the CMS that should not be plural, whereas `name` is used for plural language (as you see in most of the CMS).
For example, if you go to Posts > Add New in the admin menu, you will see that the page heading reads "Add New Post".

In the wordpress core, it is using the `singular_name` to generate the word "Post".

When you add your own custom post type, the `singular_name` value of your custom post type will be used for the heading when adding a new post of your custom type.

There are also several other places in the CMS that use the `singular_name` value.
In addition, some themes will use the function `get_post_type_labels()` to get the `singular_name` and use it to generate information about what the user is reading. For instance, if your site sells foos and bars you could use the `singular_name` to generate a button that reads "buy this foo" or "buy this bar" without coding two separate buttons.

To read more about `get_post_type_labels()` see this page:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/

Here is a an example for visual learners:
[image]

Comment: any example of the useof 'name'? again  only 'name' appears to have effects inside the CMS.

Comment: As Justin said, and as the developer page says, 'name' is the general and plural name.  When you click the 'add new' under a new post_type admin menu, you will see at the top 'Add new singularname'

Comment: @Nvim
I edited my answer to include an image for you.